# get and display excerpt posts in wordpress page

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach

I try to add post excerpt in a page but not work I added in wordpress functions.php

```
add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );
```

I enabled excerpt in this page
[image: excerpt post]

this code that I write to get excerpt post

```
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts('numberposts=5&order=DESC');
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ):?>
   <h3>
     <a href="<?php echo get_permalink($recent["ID"]);?>">
    <?php echo $recent['post_title'];?>
    </a>
 </h3>
<p><?php                                    
   //  the_excerpt(); display post excerpt here
     ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @Spartacus I create a home page That's a front page I want to display posts in `the front page`

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is? If you add that code to your homepage, it will work there too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
  $recent = new WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'order' => 'DESC',
  ) );

  if ( $recent->have_posts() ) : while ( $recent->have_posts() ) : $recent->the_post(); ?>

      <h3><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

      <?php

      the_excerpt();

      endwhile;
    endif;
  wp_reset_postdata();
?>
```

Comment: that's code will apply in `the posts page` , I want to display posts in `the front page`

Comment: You can apply this on any page you want.